# setting sleep between iterations

Tags: bash, timeout, sleep

i have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# rsync using variables
epoch=$(date +%s)
u_id=0

for (( id=1 ; ;id++ ))
do
[[ $u_id == 100 ]] && (( u_id = 1 )) || (( u_id +=1 ))

       echo $id",Danny_"$id","$id","$epoch","$u_id >> lfs.csv
       sleep 0.01

done
```

it seems that no matter what time I put as sleep time it always return me the same file size i try to make it work in order to control in the pacing of writing to the file, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Does `sleep` accept non integer arguments?

Comment: @janos GNU sleep does.

Comment: which file size doesn't change? lfs.csv? how do you check it? with `ls -l`?

Comment: it does change but in a small sizing not what i was expecting even though I increased sleep time or increased sleep time in order to check file size I use du -h